# Nosetests with coverage - cover only project's files

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

In my project I have the following structure of files:

```
..
file1.py
file2.py
tests/
    test1.py
    test2.py
```

I have installed **nosetests** and **coverage** and I run tests with the following command (from project's directory):

```
nosetests --exe --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-html
```

and then open html output

```
firefox cover/index.html
```

I expect to there the statistics for **file1.py** and **file2.py** but in addition to these two files I see the coverage for all modules, used in my application:

```
html/entities.py    8   8   0   0%
http/cookiejar.py   1097    1097    0   0%
http/cookies.py     177     177     0   0%
mimetypes.py    193     193     0   0%
netrc.py    106     106     0   0%
numbers.py  134     134     0   0%
sqlite3.py  1   1   0   0%
sqlite3/dbapi2.py   43  43  0   0%
stringprep.py   65  65  0   0%
uuid.py     338     338     0   0%
PyQt4.py    0   0   0   100%
psutil.py   794     593     37  25%
psutil/_common.py   147     52  0   65%
psutil/_compat.py   178     158     0   11%
psutil/_pslinux.py  742     556     0   25%
psutil/_psposix.py  88  71  0   19%
requests.py     28  5   0   82%
requests/adapters.py    187     77  0   59%
[...and so on...]
```

I want **coverage** to restrict to only **file1.py** and **file2.py** or, to be more clear, I'm interested to see the coverage % only for files in my project.
How do I do this?

Comment: From the Coverage documentation: https://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0.3/source.html

Comment: @KurtRaschke this is only coverage's stuff. I'm using coverage through nosetests's plugin.

Comment: Try the `--cover-package` option, then? http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/cover.html#cmdoption--cover-package

Comment: @KurtRaschke and use it like ```--cover-package=file1.py,file2.py``` and so on?

Comment: @KurtRaschke write your comment as an answer and I'll approve it. About ```--cover-package```